# Scalac bug or misunderstanding on my part?

Tags: scala, scalac

I set the `-Xfatal-warnings` compiler flag in my SBT build and sure enough this code doesn't compile:

```
package example

sealed trait Errors

object Errors {
  case class BadFirstName(name: String) extends Errors
  case class BadLastName(name: String) extends Errors
}

...

def handleError(errors: Errors): String = errors match {
  case BadFirstName(name) => s"$name is bad"
}
```

I see the error `[error] It would fail on the following input: BadLastName(_)`

But if i add a guard to the `BadFirstName` match it compiles without error or warning:

```
def handleError(errors: Errors): String = errors match {
  case BadFirstName(name) if name.startsWith("t") => s"$name is bad"
}
...
[info] Done compiling.
```

And then blows up at runtime with the dreaded `[error] scala.MatchError: BadLastName(...)`

This looks like a bug to me but I wanted to check if I've missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug, namely [SI-5365](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5365).